# Java 8 ZonedDateTime strips off .SSS if they are zeros

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, java-time

For whatever reason, ZonedDateTime in jdk 8 is removing .SSS values from the object if they are zeros. This did not happen with joda-time's DateTime object.

```
String date = "2016-10-28T02:32:12.141";
LocalDateTime ldt;
ZonedDateTime zdt;
DateTimeFormatter d = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;
ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, d);
zdt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toZonedDateTime();
System.out.println(zdt.toString());
```

This outputs: **2016-10-28T02:32:12.141Z** as expected.

However if I do:

```
String date = "2016-10-28T02:32:12.000";
LocalDateTime ldt;
ZonedDateTime zdt;
DateTimeFormatter d = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;
ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, d);
zdt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toZonedDateTime();
System.out.println(zdt.toString());
```

I end up with: **2016-10-28T02:32:12Z**

How can I get the .000 to be displayed?

Comment: Try `.format(DateTimeFormatter)`

Comment: What value `d` variable have?

Comment: d is DateTimeFormatter d = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

Comment: I also tried DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;

Comment: Before the toString(), if I look at the zdt object by setting a breakpoint there, the .000 is removed from there too. It's not a toString() issue. I am using a formatter (object d).

Comment: Tunaki is right.  the toString will strip the milliseconds from the print line.  You want to format the zdt like so: `System.out.println(zdt.format(d));`

Comment: Sorry Justin I don't see how he's right. I'm only using toString() here as an example for you lads. In my app I'm using a ZonedDateTime object directly, and the zeros are removed from that object as well. In my soap response the .000 is removed, and my schema is using a xsd:DateTime object which is referencing a ZonedDateTime object. It's not a .toString() issue.... if I use .format(d) it's still not displayed.

Comment: I am not sure why this question was marked as a duplicate as the other question is asking something different.  Nonetheless, did you try and use a different formatter?  I tried using `DateTimeFormatter d = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");` and it printed the .000.  Also, curious how you know the zeros are remoed from the ZonedDateTime object?

Comment: That works like a charm Justin - exactly what I was after. Cheers!

Comment: @JustinL The zeros are not removed from the object, they're just not used when `toString()` is called. Look at [`LocalTime.toString`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/time/LocalTime.java#LocalTime.toString%28%29) code (which `ZonedDateTime.toString()` ends up calling anyhow. It only adds the nanos `if (nanoValue > 0) {`. This is why using a formatter is the solution here, and why I marked it as duplicate, since this is the same issue as the linked post.